# SVG Not Displaying Completely in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, svg

Why is this SVG image not displaying properly in Chrome or Firefox? It displays as expected in IE 9. I tested this in Firefox 5 and 6 and Chrome 13, 14, and 15--all on Windows. I'll test Linux and ChromeOS when I get home.

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/Map_of_Rhode_Island_highlighting_Bristol_County.svg

The image is supposed to look like:

[image]

I am only seeing the red county, and nothing else. It may have something to do with the viewport:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     version="1.1"
     width="6416.0" height="9720.0"
     viewBox="-1856,-3363 6416,9720">...
```

As a note, I get this behavior for **all** county map SVG images on Wikipedia, but not necessarily other SVG images on Wikipedia.

Comment: Works for me on Firefox 3.6.18, Linux.

Comment: It doesn't work in later versions of Firefox, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what changed, but Chromium 14 & Opera 11.50 agree with current Firefox rendering (giant canvas, showing just the red country), so I'm guessing the new behavior is "correct" given the markup.

edit: Ok, I've traced this back to the [nightly changeset-range](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/pushloghtml?fromchange=e7970f6c7cdd&tochange=ba77049941c3) on Firefox development trunk.  The behavior-change was due to the top change there, for [bug 547062](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=547062), and the new behavior appears to be correct & as intended.  See the first comment on that bug -- `<clipPath>` is restricted to only contain certain elements, and `<g>` is not included in that list.  So the testcase has invalid markup.

Mechanical snail's linked validator agrees with the above -- it says: `document type does not allow element "g" here`.

Comment: I successfully rendered and validated it by removing the clippath element surrounding the g elements and also by changing id attributes that began with numbers. view-source:http://kaleb.hornsby.ws/+/img/RI.svg Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As dholbert states, other recent web browsers agree with the new Firefox rendering.

The [W3C's markup validator shows the svg file as invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F1%2F14%2FMap_of_Rhode_Island_highlighting_Bristol_County.svg&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), which is probably why.